# IntelliJ Idea undo 'don't ask again action'

Tags: intellij-idea

I've searched almost all preferences dialog on IntelliJ Idea and haven't found how to undo 'don't ask again action' on the update dialog[image: idea update project dialog]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll find what you need in the [run/debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html):

> Show dialog: Select this check box if you want to see the Update  dialog every time you perform the Update application action.

[image]

Comment: So, this means this is a server-specific option. Thank you.

Comment: I'd say it's even a run configuration-specific option. You're welcome :)