# Tomcat restart option in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there is button or short-cut to restart tomcat in Intellij ? There is restart tomcat option in Eclipse which is useful. I tried searching it online but couldn't get any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + F10 will show you following window. If you choose "restart server" and "Don't ask again" you dont need to choose for the next time.

[image]

Comment: I have choose the "Don't ask again" ，how can i restore？

Comment: @嘉恒陶 here is how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065686/intellij-idea-undo-dont-ask-again-action